# Union of thin sets is also thin

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}^N$ be open and let $A_1, A_2 \subset D$ be thin. Show that $A_1 \cup A_2$ is thin.

The definition of thin that I'm using is the following. A set $A\subset D$ is called thin if for each $c \in A$ there exists an open connected neighbourhood $U$ of $c$ and a non-zero holomorphic function on $U$ such that $U\cap A=Z(f)$, the zero locus of $f$.

I've tried simply using the definition, namely supposing that $c \in A_1\cup A_2$ and consider the case when $c \in A_1\setminus A_2$. Since $A_1$ is thin, this guarantees the existence of a $U$ and an $f$ described above. But then $U \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)=Z(f)\cup(U\cap A_2)$ and here is where I'm stuck as I have no control over $U \cap A_2$. I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: $A_2$ is closed, just stay away from it, i.e. make $U$ smaller.

Comment: I did think about shrinking $U$ but if I do that, can I still say that $U \cap A_1=Z(f)$?